# iOS: Unknown black patch between status bar and ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

I have some strange issue like having a black patch between status bar and navigation view controller view. Screenshot is below, [image]

Black space which is displayed by red box is the issue.

Comment: Add Splash screen images for all devices in project.

Comment: @Ash : Please provide some code/reference, how have you added navigation bar or done view designing.

Comment: @Mrunal : its a tab bar view and navigating to this controller through root view controller

Comment: Place an screenshot of your storyboard design along with your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. It was my mistake as navigation controller's navigation bar with black colour and forgot to hide navigation bar. Apologies for wasting your time on idiotic question.

Answer (score 0):

On your project find and click on **Image.xcassets** -> **Launch Images** and add the missing images.

Also another way is that the compiler will throw a warning to add the missing screens for your project, click on that warning and a popup will show to add the missing screen.